# ¿Cómo detener una función?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo una cierta función, algo por ejemplo que dibujase un cuadrado en un `<canvas>`,

```
function cuadrado(){

// fillRect

}
```

*Luego llevare un simple contador:*

```
var n = 0;
function contador() {
setInterval(function(){
n +=1;
},999);

}
```

*Entonces cuando hayan pasado 5 segundos, quiero que la función deje de ejecutarse, como debería hacer?*

```
if(n>5) cuadrado.break();  <= EJEMPLO
```

**Como un break en un ciclo for**

***Pero no puedo hacer otra función, que realize la acción contraria a la función `cuadrado()`, porque supongo que algunos me dirán que re-dibuje el fondo del canvas, pero esto es para más uso general***

Answer (score 4):

### Codigo

```js
var n = 0;

function contador() {

  var intervalo = setInterval(function() {

    n += 1;
    console.log(n);

    if (n == 5) {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
    }

  }, 1000);


}

contador();
```

---

### Explicacion

En tu funcion estas usando `setInterval()`, lo que ocurre es que al usarlos, dejas una ejecucion en segundo plano, que no puede ser pausada con un `break`. Para detener la ejecucion de un intervalo debes usar `clearInterval()`, usando el identificador del intervalo. Como lo puedes ver en este ejemplo:

```
var intervalo = setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
```

Posteriormente detenemos el intervalo:

```
clearInterval(intervalo);
```

> **Nota:** Recuerda que el segundo parámetros de la función `setInterval()`, es la espera que se hará entre cada ejecución, para este caso, sera 1000 mili segundos, lo cual corresponde a un segundo.

Answer (score 1):

La función `setInterval` no es muy precisa, lo mejor que puedes hacer es consultar el valor del tiempo actual en milisengundos y consultarlo constantemente, si este valor es mayor que el tiempo que tu quieres que transcurra, lo "detienes":

Ejemplo:

```js
function contador(t) {

  var before = Date.now();
  var interval;

  interval = setInterval(() => {
  
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now >= before+t*1000) {
      console.log("Tiempo!");
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
  },true);

}
contador(3); //segundos
```

O también puedes optar por usar **promesas**:

```js
function contador(t) {

  var before = Date.now();
  var interval;
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      var now = Date.now();
      if (now >= before+t*1000) {
        resolve(true);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    },true);
  });
  return promise;
}
contador(3).then(function(){
  console.log("Tiempo!");
});
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda.